# scan qrcode closing app instead of providing result

Tags: java, android, android-intent, zxing, barcode-scanner

I'm using the zxing library to provide qrcodes and scanning to an application however I'm stuck on an issue.  When attempting to scan, I've tried several methods.  The recommended:

```
IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
integrator.initiateScan();
```

or the Intent method:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
this.startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Both appear to work fine as the Scan app or choose the app to handle the intent dialog appears.  However, after scanning, the app immediately closes.  No errors and no results.  Just bye-bye.

method to catch the result, note the Log.d immediately after super() is never displayed.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "resultcode = " + resultCode);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case IntentIntegrator.REQUEST_CODE:
            IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(
                    requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (scanResult == null) {
                return;
            }
            final String result = scanResult.getContents(); // Your result

            if (result != null) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Your result is: " + result);
            }
            break;
        default:
    }
}
```

I've seen references in some tutorials explaining how to implement zxing make entries in the AndroidManifest.xml.  Seen below:

```
 <activity android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"
       android:screenOrientation="landscape"
       android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
       android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
       android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
       <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
       </intent-filter>
       <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN"/>
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

I'm just not having any luck so far and the lack of logs isn't helping point me in any direction.

I'm using Android Studio and have gradle setup for the libs in dependencies:

```
compile files('libs/core-3.1.1.jar')
compile files('libs/android-integration-3.1.1.jar')
```

Help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not with zxing, but rather with the way you start it. The second parameter of the `startActivityForResult` method is a `requestCode` ([documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int))). You would then check that `requestCode` on `onActivityResult` to handle the response. Also, do not call `super` first in `onActivityResult`.

For example:

```
startActivityForResult(intent, 123);
```

will cause Android to call onActivityResult with request code 123

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 123 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        //do some stuff...
    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that the onActivityResult is not being called, otherwise I would see the Log.d message before attempting to handle.

Comment: how to get core 3.1.1 jar?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
if (scanResult != null) {
  // handle scan result
 }
 // else continue with any other code you need in the method
 ...
  }
```

Comment: afraid it still closes after removing the super() call.  I've tried using the IntentIntegrator as well as creating a new Intent.

Answer (score 0):

try to implement this, hope it might work.

in onCrearte() -- call the doScan() method.

//OnClick of Scan  button.

```
Button btn_scan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stbcheck_btn_scan);
        btn_scan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                doScan();
            }
        });
```

doScan():

//Bar code Scanning Option and  API Integration

```
public void doScan() {
        IntentIntegrator.initiateScan(this);
    }
```

onActivityResult():

```
public void onActivityResult(int request, int result, Intent i) {
        IntentResult scan=IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(request, result, i);

        if (scan!=null) {
            //format.setText(scan.getFormatName());
            //Set the returned content from Scanner to edit text
            et_stbNo.setText(scan.getContents());
        }
    }
```

NOTE: You must call these onSavedInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState() methods, as your activity is destroyed and recreated again while changing the orientation.

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle state) {
    //state.putString("format", format.getText().toString());
    state.putString("contents", et_stbNo.getText().toString());
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle state) {
    //format.setText(state.getString("format"));
    et_stbNo.setText(state.getString("contents"));
}
```

Hope it helps:

Answer (score 0):

Use below code it is working for my code.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (result != null)
    {
        if (result.getContents() == null)
        {

        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
    else
    {
        // This is important, otherwise the result will not be passed to the fragment
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```